# Are parameters in a PL/SQL Stored Procedure "IN" by default?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parameters, input

Rephrasing the question: Are this two code snippets different in any way?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
ASSIGN_EMAIL(E_NO INT, F_NAME VARCHAR2, L_NAME VARCHAR2)

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
ASSIGN_EMAIL(E_NO IN INT, F_NAME IN VARCHAR2, L_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
```

Comment: Please learn to use the online documentation.  It would taken you less effort to look it up that it took you to type this question. Mat has kindly given you a link to the specific section.  I suggest you bookmark the homepage for the entire set.  Here is the link for 10gR2: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage  The docs for other versions are also available.

Comment: @APC. Thanks for the tip, I couldn't find this specific information using several Google queries (it is not like Oracle Documentation is small). Still, if asking something that is basic for another programmer fits "not a real question" criterion, then I think you guys should vote to close about 100 of the 106 questions I answered.

Comment: FWIW I didn't downvote you.  However, I did vote to close.  There is a general feeling that too many questions on SO could be answered instead if the questioner has read the manual before asking the question.  See this thread on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason

Comment: @APC. I'm aware of that, that's the reason for my comment. As for the feature request, this keeps getting proposed at meta... And everytime a lot of users provides counter arguments (such as @smartcaveman highly up-voted answer). My point here is, right or wrong, until one of the proposed features is actually implemented, I don't think it is right to close basic answers with "not a real question". Anyway, I think this discussion better fits meta, so we should move it there :D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `IN` is the default. Check table 8.1 in the Oracle [PL/SQL subprogram](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#BCFHBGBI) docs.